# binding and working of spring form with the back end object in SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to SpringMvc. Could anyone please explain the binding and working of spring form with the back end object in SpringMVC.

some of the doubts are 
Consider the scenario, there is a form which will take user details and it will be persisted to db
1) I have seen a controller which creates User's instances and adding the attribute to ModelMap. What is the use of that?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/form.html")
public ModelAndView form(ModelMap map){

    User user= new User();
    map.addAttribute("user",user);
    return new ModelAndView("form","command",map); 

}
```

2) What is the use of command here? in the form page, this 'user' object will be available?

*form.jsp

```
<form:form.... action="formprocess.html" commandName="user"/>
```

(If I want to use 'user' should it   have  been already created as above?)

3) Why do we use @ModelAttribute? Why do we use Model instead of ModelMap?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/formprocess.html")
public String form(@ModelAttribute("user"User user,Model model){

    model.addAttribute("username",user.getUserName());
    return "formprocess";

}
```

could anyone please explain or provide a link which has sufficient explanations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Regarding `ModelMap`, model map is used to pass certain data from you controller to the view which you delegate from that controller. You add attributes from controller and later on get attributes from view page.
2. Regarding `commandName`, `commandName="user"` this is something that the controller uses to map the form fields to a particular bean or POJO fields. So you do not have to manually get all the request parameters and set it yo pojos when a form is submitted and controller receives the event.
3. Regarding `@ModelAttribute`, since you use `@ModelAttribute("user")` as method parameter, spring container will look for a a command name `user` from `request` object and map it's properties to the pojos defined in `@ModelAttribute` viz in your case `User class`.

**Regarding difference between Model and ModelMap :**
`ModelMap` subclasses `LinkedHashMap`, and provides some additional conveniences to make it a bit easier to use by controllers

- `addAttribute` can be called with just a value, and the map key is then inferred from the type.
- The `addAttribute` methods all return the `ModelMap`, so you can chain method called together, e.g. `modelMap.addAttribute('x', x).addAttribute('y',y)`
- The `addAttribute` methods checks that the values aren't null
- The generic type of `ModelMap` is fixed at `Map<String, Object>`, which is the only one that makes sense for a view model.

So nothing earth-shattering, but enough to make it a bit nicer than a raw `Map`. Spring will let you use either one.

You can also use the `Model` interface, which provides nothing other than the `addAttribute` methods, and is implemented by the `ExtendedModelMap` class which itself adds further conveniences.